# How to properly create a custom exception with a message?

Tags: c++, exception, c++11

I'm new to C++ and I'm trying to create a custom exception that takes a message in its ctor.

What I have right now is this:

```
class LevelLoadException : public std::exception
{
public:
    LevelLoadException(std::string msg) : m_message(msg) { }
    const char * what () const throw ()
    {
        return m_message.c_str();
    }
private:
    std::string m_message;
};
```

In my calling code, I have this as part of a switch statements (`c` is a char, or more specifically, `c = line[x];` where `x` is an `int` and `line` is a `std::string`);

```
default:
    throw LevelLoadException("Invalid Character in Level: " + c);
```

The problem is that my Exception gets a completely unrelated string (that's part of the same method that throws: `throw std::exception("There is more than 1 player start in the level.")`).

I have excluded a logic bug - my program reaches the line where the correct exception with the correct string is thrown. So I'm pretty sure it's a lifetime/memory management problem.

To my understanding, C++ is copy-by-value by default. So I thought that calling the ctor of `LevelLoadException` would immediately copy the string. But it seems that there is some pointer stuff going on, since the string that I'm building seems like a C string (`const char*`).

I looked at the `std::exception` class, and this takes a `const char* const&` as the message and then does some C-like strcopy/malloc under the hood (MSVC / Visual Studio 2012 Update 4).

I'm not a hundred percent sure what I actually need. I think what I want is a string that's built in the caller, then moved/copied into the Exception (which now owns a copy of the string that's only owned by the exception) and then the one in the caller is destroyed when it's out of scope.

Can someone give me [a pointer](http://xkcd.com/138/) to what I should be doing differently to do this properly?

Comment: And you catch a std exception ?

Comment: @Christophe No, I have `catch(LevelLoadException& e)` in the consumer.

Comment: You should derive from `std::runtime_error` instead of `std::exception`. Then your class can be reduced to a [couple of lines](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9666bd1e13f8f25c).

Comment: If you decide not to go the `std::runtime_error` route, you should consider doing on-demand formatting, as an allocation error during the creation of those `std::string`s can cause trouble.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`"Invalid Character in Level: " + c` doesn't do what you think it does. It means "a `char*` pointer that is offset by `N` bytes from the beginning of the string literal", where `N` is the ASCII code of the character stored in `c`. Chances are high the literal is actually shorter than `N` characters, in which case this program contains a buffer overrun and exhibits undefined behavior.

Make it

```
throw LevelLoadException(std::string("Invalid Character in Level: ") + c);
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. So `"string"` returns a `char *` (for C backwards compat) and then I'm doing pointer math (char c becoming the numeric value 99)? Converting the `"string"` into a C++ string uses the `operator+` of `std::string`?

Comment: @Praetorian: Ah, right. I'll make the correction, though it doesn't fundamentally change the answer.

Comment: @MichaelStum: You got it (modulo `99` actually being the ASCII code of whatever character happens to be stored in the variable `c`; that was my mistake, sorry for confusion).

Comment: So it was pure luck that I got some other valid string and not garbage or an Access Violation :) (Well, bad luck maybe since an Access Violation would've been clearer). Thanks, it works now!

Comment: @MichaelStum: compilers often lump all constant static data into the same chunk of the program's generated binary - and often prefer to lump all strings together - so you can easily see behavior like you describe when you do weird things to string literal addresses.